# Firebase util Path(items/) contains an empty keyMap

Tags: firebase

I am using firebase util like:

```
                var join = Firebase.util.intersection(
                    fbRefs.rooms().child(sPalaceId).child(sRoomId).child('items'),
                    fbRefs.items()
                );

                return $firebase(join);
```

It's working okay EXCEPT that sometimes when I am trying to create a new item in FB for the first time it throws me this error after a successful insert(when I refresh the page the data are there...):

```
Path(items/-JXqM4sqhCAOl2012eOP) contains an empty keyMap
```

Using AngularFire 0.7.1

Any idea please?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without AngularFire? And move it from "sometimes when" to "always when"? That would make it a lot easier to investigate why you see this behavior.

Comment: That's the problem Frank. I can't reproduce it and I am using the same technique everywhere and it works so idk. I was just hoping that someone has the same experience.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because it cannot determine which fields belong to which table. You can provide the keymap to prevent this.

```
var index = fbRefs.rooms().child(sPalaceId).child(sRoomId).child('items');
var items = fbRefs.items();
var join = Firebase.util.intersection(
   {ref: index, keyMap: ['foo', 'bar']},
   {ref: items, keyMap: ['baz']}
);
```

Note that we'll have a new, much more user-friendly version of the join libs out in the next few weeks.

Comment: and also working @kato ? because I heard that from you at the beginning of the summer and this one is super bugy. I just found another problem heh. Anyway, good luck with development!

Comment: @Kato what do the keyMap values represent?

Comment: good question @MurraySmith I was 10mins ago trying to implement this but it didn't synchronize my data. My items child under roomId looks like: <someid>:true, <someid2>:true

Comment: Some info: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/blob/e4cbfb17546a9d2612934971d03f749215c11529/src/join/README.md#keymaps